# Burninate [adding]

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, burninate-request, tags

The tag [adding](/questions/tagged/adding) seems to be used on any post with a mention of the word "add".

It's being used for adding numbers, adding properties to objects, anything.

Could this tag be burninated? Or could we come to a consensus on what it *should* mean and give it a tagwiki?

Comment: That tag is never going to go anywhere, tag wiki or not. It is a meta tag and deserves to burn.

Comment: If we burn that, we should probably burn [tag:subtracting] too, and replace with [tag:math] with applicable (or is there a better tag to replace with?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I removed the tag from about ~260 questions.

The tags [adding](/questions/tagged/adding) and [subtracting](/questions/tagged/subtracting) have been burninated.

[image]

Comment: Both are now on my kill list.  Thanks, Josh!